# C, use int variable as array size inside structure

Tags: c, struct

I would like to define array size inside a structure by using a parameter of this structure. Does C permit to do something like this ?

```c
struct queue {
    int head;
    int top;
    int size;
    struct action action[size];
};
```

Comment: @PhilippClaßen it was closed because the duplicate answer tells exactly about flexible array members.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't. Since `action` is not a dynamic variable, the compiler needs to know at compile time how much space it needs for `action`. `size` was not even initialized. Anyway, you could see this just by trying to compile.

Comment: You seem to have missed the "something like this" part, and something like this is certainly possible with flexible array members, see the referred question.

Comment: In the referred question, in the answers the code contains pointers. Here there are no pointers. But if you think you can do this, why don't you try to compile it? If I try to compile the code I get this `main.c:5:26: error: ‘size’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     struct action action[size];`, like I was expecting in the answer

Comment: Kindly explain your understanding of "something like this" clause.

Comment: I think "something like this" means "if you try this code or something near this code". I wouldn't consider using pointers and malloc something like the code inserted.

Comment: Something like this is, to quote, "_define array size inside a structure by using a parameter of this structure_", and that's _exactly_ what FLAs are for.

Comment: Bereal is right, that was my question. Sorry if it's unclear. And I got the answer, thank you all.

Answer (score -2):

The `size` is not known at the time of defining the struct. Therefore it is impossible for the compiler to understand how large the result will be. Typically, you would first allocate memory for the struct, and have a `struct action *action;` member. After initializing the struct, you use `instance->action = calloc(instance->size, sizeof *instance->action)` to allocate memory for the array.